# How to Autoresize Masks after changing position of some view from programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, frame, autoresize

I am working on app and I am in trying to support my app for iPhone 4,5,6 and 6plus with one view. I chose to Autoresize for this operation, I am not going in discussion why I didn't chose Autolayout.

Now I have a Save button with Autoresizing mask set as shown in picture flexible of all corner. and somewhere after I need to change Save button position via code after setting updated frame of Save button, its corner flexibility change to static and this stick on all devices what I added new frames, and this looks quite odd in 6plus and 4.

Here below is my code to update frame.

```
    [self.saveProfileButton setFrame:CGRectMake(self.saveProfileButton.frame.origin.x, PIOYPositionOfSaveButtonForEditingProfile, self.saveProfileButton.frame.size.width, self.saveProfileButton.frame.size.height)];
self.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
self.saveProfileButton.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin |
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin);
```

I am trying to reset these flexible margins because of this goes to static.

I am looking for help how to make this flexible margins after updating this button frames.
[image]